# Having trouble finding the correct item in google guice to add to classpath

Tags: java, import, classpath, guice

In online tutorials, I see a lot of references to com.google.inject.* but I'm having trouble finding the correct library to add to my classpath from the guice source at https://github.com/google/guice.

In the end I find things like javax.inject but I was hoping to find the lib that would be able to also give me abstractModule and everything else that often gets mentioned in those tutorials.

Is there a proper way to set this up so I can just use com.google.inject.* as well?

Additional info: I am using intelliJ and am not looking to use maven for this. I want to figure out how to do it without maven before I try to figure out how to do it with maven

Comment: The first line of the README is : *Latest release: 4.1*. Click on the link, and you'll have all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Guice 4.1 release jar from here and add it to your classpath:

https://github.com/google/guice/releases/download/4.1/guice-4.1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

Each release has it's wiki page with maven coordinates **and** download links.

For example, last version is 4.1:

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice41